# MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday

Tags: mysql, events, scheduler

Here's my query

```
CREATE EVENT
RESET ON SCHEDULE AT TIMESTAMP DO
UPDATE `ndic`.`students`
SET `status` = '0';
```

How can I update status to "0" at 1 pm every day.

What can I use instead of `TIMESTAMP`?

Answer (score 71):

This might be too late for your work, but here is how I did it. I want something run everyday at 1AM - I believe this is similar to what you are doing. Here is how I did it:

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  DO
    # Your awesome query
```

Comment: Is `TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE)` necessary? Seems to work with just `CURRENT_DATE + Interval ..`

Comment: This is incredible! I had not realized how the "starts" was calculated, until I executed the consultation and then I said: it means "Tomorrow at 00:01:00" ... Thank you very much!

Comment: Is there a way, to execute this Schedule, every day from 13:00 - 14:00 every minute?

Answer (score 43):

The [documentation on CREATE EVENT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-event.html) is quite good, but it takes a while to get it right.

You have two problems, first, **making the event recur**, second, **making it run at 13:00 daily**.

This example creates a recurring event.

```
CREATE EVENT e_hourly
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
    COMMENT 'Clears out sessions table each hour.'
    DO
      DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
```

When in the command-line MySQL client, you can:

```
SHOW EVENTS;
```

This lists each event with its metadata, like if it should run once only, or be recurring.

The second problem: **pointing the recurring event to a specific schedule item**.

By trying out different kinds of expression, we can come up with something like:

```
CREATE EVENT IF NOT EXISTS `session_cleaner_event`
ON SCHEDULE
  EVERY '1 13' DAY_HOUR
  COMMENT 'Clean up sessions at 13:00 daily!'
  DO
    DELETE FROM site_activity.sessions;
```

*Update*, long over-due: [The *interval* with the unit "DAY_HOUR" takes an *expression* that looks like 'day-number hour-number'.](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/expressions.html#temporal-intervals) I have updated the oft-accepted solution to match that. Thanks, commenters for clarifying!

Comment: This doesn't work for me.  I tried with 10 DAY_HOUR and it simply executed immediately and scheduled itself.  Nor do I see why it would.  As I read the MySQL docs, DAY_HOUR is a way of specifying days and hours from now - it is still an interval.  Or have I completely misunderstood?

Comment: Agree with @Adam. This doesn't seem to meet the requirement of running daily at 1pm. based on a few quick tests I think it would end up executing every 13 hours. `select current_timestamp()
,date_add(current_timestamp(), interval 13 day_hour);`

Comment: `CREATE EVENT e_specific_time
    ON SCHEDULE
      SELECT end_date FROM table_name WHERE end_date=CURRENT_DATE
    DO
      UPDATE active=0 FROM table_name WHERE end_date=CURRENT_DATE;`
How can I run this?

Answer (score 21):

Try this

```
CREATE EVENT event1
ON SCHEDULE EVERY '1' DAY
STARTS '2012-04-17 13:00:00' -- should be in the future
DO
-- your statements
END
```

Answer (score 16):

```
DROP EVENT IF EXISTS xxxEVENTxxx;
CREATE EVENT xxxEVENTxxx
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  DO
    --process;
```

**¡IMPORTANT!->**

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Comment: SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON; -> used to activate mysql events, if not created but not run ever.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score 15):

My use case is similar, except that I want a log cleanup event to run at 2am every night.  As I said in the comment above, the DAY_HOUR doesn't work for me.  In my case I don't really mind potentially missing the first day (and, given it is to run at 2am then 2am tomorrow is almost always the next 2am) so I use:

```
CREATE EVENT applog_clean_event
ON SCHEDULE 
    EVERY 1 DAY
    STARTS str_to_date( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d 0200'), '%Y%m%d %H%i' ) + INTERVAL 1 DAY
COMMENT 'Test'
DO
```

Comment: Couldn't you use `CURRENT_DATE()` instead of `str_to_date( date_format(now(), '%Y%m%d 0200'), '%Y%m%d %H%i' )`? Anyway thanks.

Comment: Yes - except that I want to be able to specify that it runs at 0200 each day. If you use current_date then it would run each day at whatever time you happened to run the script to create it.

Comment: Oh, I thought CURRENT_DATE returned a date with format: yyyy-MM-dd meaning that the time would be 00:00 but perhaps I wasn't right.

Comment: My appologies.  You were right.  I was getting my SQL implementations mixed up -  I also work with Oracle pl/sql and there current_date is a date object containing the current date and time in the users timezone - more like MySQLs now(). So yes, if you want it run at 0000 then curent_date would probably work.  If you want to specify the time ir runs each day, however, then you need my solution above.

Comment: ah, good to know. Not going to be picky but you could actually do something like this `(CURRENT_DATE() + INTERVAL X HOUR) + INTERVAL 1 DAY` but as you said, with Oracle it might not work the same. Thank you for the info.

Answer (score 2):

```
CREATE EVENT test_event_03
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 1 MINUTE
STARTS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
ENDS CURRENT_TIMESTAMP + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
DO
   INSERT INTO messages(message,created_at)
   VALUES('Test MySQL recurring Event',NOW());
```