# Give me a logic how to run a specific code for the background when the selected time is met

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

> I'm making a program for a hotel management where a user input a
>   check-in date and check-out date If the client stays beyond this time,
>   he is charged for another day.
>
> my main problem here is that how can i execute my code that not needed to push a button.

my idea is use a timer and set a time interval every hour so that it checks
the database if the system time and check-out time is met. any ideas?

Comment: Maybe this can help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday

Comment: any other ideas? im not that familiar with MYSQL even though i'm using  SQLServer, still only basic codes for sql i know. i'm more of a vb guy. thanks for the reference

Comment: You could use  [Quartz](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: Why do you need to change the database data exactly at check-out time? MS SQL server comes with an agent that can run code every day at a given time. You could create a job that runs an update query every day.