# MySQL Event Scheduler run 10 times per day

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I want to run a query statement 10 times per day. I know I should use event scheduler like

> ```
> CREATE EVENT event_name
>   ON SCHEULE
>     EVERY 1 DAY
>     STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
>   DO
>     # Your query
> ```
>
> But How can I run it 10 times per day?
>   Thx

Comment: You could run it every 144 minutes

Comment: @TheVedge Yes? What dose the code look like then?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE EVENT event_name
  ON SCHEDULE
    EVERY 144 MINUTE
    STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE) + INTERVAL 1 DAY + INTERVAL 1 HOUR)
  DO
    # Your query
```

for 10 times in a day you can set like this means `(24/10)=2.4` & `(2.4*60)=144` minutes so it will execute 10 times in a day