# Delete a row after certain time using trigger

Tags: database, oracle, triggers, database-trigger

I want to create a trigger which deletes the rows in the table automatically after 3 months if the status is not updated.

[Create Trigger to delete rows that are >90 days old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24167613/create-trigger-to-delete-rows-that-are-90-days-old/24167965)

This was the reference through which I was trying to do it but could not do it.
Kindly help me to figure out this.

Comment: you have created a job scheduler that through automatic run this scheduler and execute from your procedure.for more information please refer this link [https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e25494/scheduse.htm#ADMIN034]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are looking for `dbms_scheduler`.

```
begin
dbms_scheduler.create_job (
    job_name => 'DEL_BEFORE_3MONTH_JOB',
    job_type => 'PLSQL_BLOCK',
    job_action => 'BEGIN DELETE FROM YOUR_TABLE WHERE ADD_MONTHS(YOUR_DATE,3) < TRUNC(SYSDATE); COMMIT; END;',
    start_date => sysdate,
    repeat_interval => 'FREQ=DAILY;BYHOUR=12', -- NOON
    enabled => true    
);
end;
/
```

Refer this [document](https://oracle-base.com/articles/10g/scheduler-10g) for more information on it.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank You!!!! this solved my problem and sorry for the late reply