# Mysql event to delete record if date

Tags: mysql, date

I have little problem, because I have in table element "waznosc" which is date. And I want to delete records where date = "today". I tried something like this:

```
CREATE EVENT rec ON DATE() DO DELETE FROM userproduct WHERE waznosc=CURDATE()
```

But it doesn't work :/ Somebody have idea what can be wrong or know any other way how can I solve my problem?

Comment: `ON DATE()` is wrong. When is this event supposed to run?

Comment: See the syntax at https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-event.html

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "it doesn't work".  How do you know it didn't work?  Is there an error message?

Comment: possible duplicate of [MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday)