# MySQL Event Scheduler run daily in a specific time frame

Tags: mysql, wordpress, cron

I wrote a query in MySQL which I want to run daily on our wordpress server. Using Cronjobs gave me a lot of collate errors, so I took the easier rout with the Event Scheduler which is easier to implement via phpMyAdmin.

Now I would like to run the query only at specific times: Once per hour, between 8 am and 5 pm.

Is this possible using Event Scheduler? I know of:

```
STARTS = ...
ENDS = ...
```

But as far as I know, that only sets global values (start and end once). Is there any possibility to set a recurring daily end? Or do I have to use cron for that?

Comment: You do not include your mysql commands, your scripts, your SH or bat script. This question is not complete and cannot be answered.

Comment: Neither of these are needed to answer my question. Since I use Event Scheduler, a sh or bat script is not used. I want to know if setting a specific recurring time in event scheduler is possible or not. Please advise me what information you need additionally.

Comment: Have a look @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday

Comment: I saw that thread. The problem there is different to mine, since it only refers to setting a daily recurring time. I need to make further changes to Event Scheduler (daily time frame), hence my question.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue

The problem from what I see is that you want to do two things:

- Run something once per hour (`interval`)
- But not continue doing this action outside of a specific daily timeframe.

The first part is very easily to take care of using the example from:
[MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday/14621908#14621908)

The second part is the one that creates the complexity.

### Solutions

You have two available solutions that I can think of:

1. Schedule an event with interval 1 hour, and add a check in your SQL statement / function / procedure to check that that time of day is within the specific time interval you want.
2. Schedule multiple events (9-10) for the specific times e.g. (8:59am, 9:59am...4:59am)

Personally I would prefer solution one since it is much easier to change a value in your script than have to reschedule / manage 9-10 events.

### Quick Example

```
delimiter |

CREATE EVENT hours
    ON SCHEDULE
      EVERY 1 HOUR
      STARTS (TIMESTAMP(CURRENT_DATE))
    DO
      proc_label:BEGIN

         IF curtime() >= "08:00" OR curtime() <= "17:00" THEN
          LEAVE proc_label;
        END IF;

        select 1+1;
      END |

delimiter ;
```

Comment: Option 1 seems like a good workaround for my problem, thanks! I will leave it open for a while, if somebody else has another idea.

Answer (score 0):

Just a little sugestion, to change from OR to AND.

```
IF curtime() >= "08:00" AND curtime() <= "17:00" THEN
      LEAVE proc_label;
```

Comment: It should be edit to another answer, but not standalone answer