# MySQL event on given hour

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to create event that would run function daily on given time (to be more precise, 7:00 and 17:00), I've created this code:

```
DELIMITER |

CREATE EVENT kill_sleepers_event
    ON SCHEDULE EVERY (7, 17) DAY_HOUR
    COMMENT 'Clean up sleepers at 7:00 and 17:00 daily!'
    DO
      BEGIN
        SELECT func();
      END |
```

Workbench doesn't show any syntax error, but when I try to run it, there is error:

> Error Code: 1241. Operand should contain 1 column(s)

So I want to ask you if it's possible to have event with multiple launching time or I have to wrote them as two separate entities?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday)

Comment: As I said, I don't want to run it once a day. I know how to do it. I want to run it multiple times a day at specific hour.