# is there any way to delete data from database automatically when user set date in laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-scheduler

**Delete database data** when user **set date** when that **date is reached**.

```
<form class="needs-validation" action="{{ route('set-expiration') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="end_date" />
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Set Date</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Have you done research, did you try?

Answer (score 0):

You can create an event in MySQL to delete records

Reference [MySQL Event Scheduler on a specific time everyday](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday)