# mySQL Update column checking other field value

Tags: mysql, sql, database, mysql-workbench

### i have my app configuration values in table for example.

```
id   appid   keyValue   dataValue   
1    app1    hitcount       3
2    app1    lasthit    2022-03-23 13:15:56
```

---

[image: Screenshoot]

i was trying to write a query in MySQL to reset hitcount = 0 if lasthit date change for example if 23 changed to 24 i want to reset 0 hitcount i wrote this query but getting error [**Error Code: 1093.**].

```
  update appconfig 
  SET dataValue = IF ( (select day(dataValue) 
                        from appconfig 
                        where appid  = 'app1' 
                        and keyValue   = 'lasthit'
                        ) > day(utc_timestamp()),0,dataValue
                      )
where appid  = 'app1' 
and keyValue   = 'hitcount'
```

Please advice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an INNER JOIN

But such a Query belongs in an [EVENT HANDLER](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3070277/mysql-event-scheduler-on-a-specific-time-everyday)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE appconfig (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `appid` VARCHAR(4),
>   `keyValue` VARCHAR(8),
>   `dataValue` VARCHAR(10)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO appconfig
>   (`id`, `appid`, `keyValue`, `dataValue`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'app1', 'hitcount', '3'),
>   ('2', 'app1', 'lasthit', '2022-03-23'),
>     ('3', 'app2', 'hitcount', '3'),
>   ('4', 'app2', 'lasthit', '2022-03-22');
> ```

> ```
> UPDATE appconfig a1
> INNER JOIN (SELECT `appid` FROM appconfig WHERe DATE(`dataValue`) < current_date() 
> AND `keyValue` = 'lasthit' ) a
> ON a.`appid` = a1.`appid`
> SET 
>     dataValue = 0
> WHERE
>  keyValue = 'hitcount'
> ```

> ```
> SELECT * FROM appconfig
> ```
>
> ```
> id | appid | keyValue | dataValue 
> -: | :---- | :------- | :---------
>  1 | app1  | hitcount | 3         
>  2 | app1  | lasthit  | 2022-03-23
>  3 | app2  | hitcount | 0         
>  4 | app2  | lasthit  | 2022-03-22
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=4cd67ae5f3115a550c0ebb469191db6d)*